# how to reset the column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

i have table with 9 records that 2 records with _id = 1 was deleted:

```
id   |   name    |    index    |    _id
 1        a            1             1
 8        b            3             1
 9        c            7             1
 10       d            4             1
 15       e            2             1
 16       d            1             2
 17       e            2             2
```

and I want to reset the index of _id = 1 like this:

```
id   |   name    |    index    |    _id
 1        a            1             1
 8        b            2             1
 9        c            3             1
 10       d            4             1
 15       e            5             1
 16       d            1             2
 17       e            2             2
```

i 'd use this query

```
declare @_idCount int = (select count(*) from tbl where _id = 1), 
        @index int = 1

while(@_idCount > 0)
    begin
        update tbl
        set code = @index
        where _id = 1

        set @index = @index + 1
        set @picCount = @picCount - 1
    end
```

but this code is set all of record with same code.
what can i do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT id,
           name,
           [index],
           [_id],
           new_index = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [_id] 
                                         ORDER BY [id])
    FROM dbo.tbl
)
UPDATE CTE
SET [index] = new_index;
```